# I've answered a question wrong. Shall I delete that post?

Tags: discussion

I've answered a question wrong because I read the question incorrectly. Shall I delete that post? What is the right thing to do. 
Deleting will not affect reps but keeping it there could be.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

The only way to learn is by making mistakes.  And you might as well learn from the mistakes of others.  Few things are more instructive than a great wrong answer.

Regrettably, SO discourages wrong answers with a reputation penalty.  Great wrong answers are nearly extinct because unscrupulous answerers delete them for their reputation.

The best thing you could do is to edit your wrong answer.  Add a bold header to indicate the answer is wrong.  Explain why it is wrong and why you originally thought it was right.

Comment: @TylerH Noticed your edit of this 10 year old answer to a largely different answer. Why was that?

Comment: @Andomar I did not change it into a 'largely different' answer, I just removed noise. I was improving it to remove unrelated opinion/meta commentary since it's the accepted answer. You can learn without making mistakes, and the question is not about how to learn, it is about whether a wrong answer should be edited into a right one. Ironic that you did not follow your own advice here and rolled back an improvement/correction to an answer.

Comment: BTW, age of a post is irrelevant to whether it needs to be edited or not.

Comment: @TylerH I agree with Andomar with regards to your edit here. The paragraphs you removed outline the *reasoning* behind his recommendation to edit wrong answers instead of deleting them, and IMO it's entirely proper for that reasoning to be in the answer. (I fundamentally *don't* agree with the answer itself; a wrong answer with a "this is wrong" disclaimer at the top is *usually* useless and better deleted. Answers that merely explain why a given approach to a problem won't work *are* occasionally useful but even those shouldn't be structured as a wrong answer with a disclaimer above it.)

Answer (score 14):

Yes, unless you can edit (i.e. replace) the answer to make it correct, the right thing to do is delete it.

It serves no purpose being there.

If the answer is less than 60 days old and has a score of less than 3 you'll lose any reputation you gained from up-votes, but regain any you lost from down-votes.

Answer (score 1):

I find it depends on how "wrong" my answer is. If I realise my answer is completely incorrect I delete it. If my answer is simply not very good then I update it and either mention that the other answers are better or improve my answer.